# HTML5 video loop not working in Chrome (from Cloudfront)

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, amazon-cloudfront

I have the following HTML5 video element in my test page:

```
<video width="1280" height="720" loop="loop">
  <source src="http://d1dsyb3mv0b0i6.cloudfront.net/test/lines.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  Your browser does not support the video element.
</video>
```

I want it to loop its playback, so I set the `loop="loop"` (and I also tried simply `loop`), but for some reason Chrome 23 does not restart the video when it ends. I specifically moved the video to a Cloudfront Download distribution to get the partial content request support on the server, which is supposedly needed for Chrome to perform looped playback, but unfortunately that does not seem to make a difference. Note that in Safari all works fine. Then again, Safari has no trouble looping even a local video file, so it does not need a server with partial content request support.

It seems to be Cloudfront-related, since this movie does loop correctly: `http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4`.

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You need to properly set the `content-type` metadata on the S3 object to reflect the correct MIME type of the file.  Chrome tends to be more picky about this than other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I have uploaded `trailer.mp4` to Cloudfront (S3) as well and that **does** work. This mp4 even works from the local file system, so unlike what I thought, I don't specifically need to play the video from a server that supports partial content requests. So it seems that the `lines.mp4` video is somehow different from the `trailer.mp4` video. I'm very curious to find what the difference is that makes this video not loopable by Chrome, whereas it loops fine in Safari...

Answer (score 0):

Loop worked for me, but try replacing loop with the commands:

```
autoplay onended="this.currentTime=0"
```

or

```
autoplay onended="this.load()"
```

The second option results in flicker during the reload. The first ran smoothly, but currentTime can behave differently, depending on other settings. Hope that works.